# Issue selecting a specific amount of words in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm creating a macro the copy 5000 words from a word document and paste it to a new one:

```
Sub Excerpt_Selection()

Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=5000, Extend:=wdExtend 
Selection.Copy
Documents.Add.Activate
Selection.Paste
```

The code above works fine, however, it doesn't select 5000 words, it selects around 4100. The documents I'll be getting the words from is a book. Any ideas on how to get it to select exactly 5000 words?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is the problem, the `Words` method and the `wdWord` constant (as it applies to the Selection object) also capture punctuation mark as a "word", so "Hello, world!" consists of 4 words: `"hello"`, `", "`, `"world"`, and `"!"`

Answer (score 0):

the `Words` method and the `wdWord` constant (as it applies to the `Selection` object) also capture punctuation mark as a "word", so "Hello, world!" consists of 4 words: `"hello"`, `", "`, `"world"`, and `"!"`

Word isn't my specialty, and there may be a better approach than this which is kind of brute force:

```
Const punctuation as String = ",./?\:;" '<~~ Modify as needed with additional marks
Sub Excerpt_Selection()
Dim wCount as Long
Dim selectedWords as Range

Do

    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Set selectedWords = Selection.Range
    With selectedWords
        If InStr(1, punctuation, RTrim(.Words(.Words.Count))) = 0 Then wCount = wCount + 1
    End With
Loop While wCount < 5000

Selection.Copy
Documents.Add.Activate
Selection.Paste

End Sub
```